# How to get emailid from Facebook Login in using facebook sdk version 3.22.0

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using only one button when i click on the button then i want to get the email id.
Here is my code and get the ID and name, but emailid cannot get.I am using facebook sdk version 3.22.0 Please help me.

enter code here

package com.example.testintegration;

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.example.testfbintegration.R;
import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner;
import com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner.RequestListener;
import com.facebook.android.DialogError;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.DialogListener;
import com.facebook.android.FacebookError;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static String APP_ID = "862722850469774"; // Replace with your App ID

    // Instance of Facebook Class
    private Facebook facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
    private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
    String FILENAME = "AndroidSSO_data";
    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;

    // Buttons
    Button btnFbLogin;
    /*Button btnFbGetProfile;
    Button btnPostToWall;
    Button btnShowAccessTokens;*/


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        btnFbLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_fblogin);
        /*btnFbGetProfile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_get_profile);
        btnPostToWall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_fb_post_to_wall);
        btnShowAccessTokens = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_show_access_tokens);*/
        mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);

        /**
         * Login button Click event
         * */
        btnFbLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("Image Button", "button Clicked");
                //loginToFacebook();
                logfacebook();
            }
        });

        /**
         * Getting facebook Profile info
         * *//*
        btnFbGetProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getProfileInformation();
            }
        });

        *//**
         * Posting to Facebook Wall
         * *//*
        btnPostToWall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                postToWall();
            }
        });

        *//**
         * Showing Access Tokens
         * *//*
        btnShowAccessTokens.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showAccessTokens();
            }
        });*/




    }

    public void logfacebook()
    {
         Session.openActiveSession(MainActivity.this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

             // callback when session changes state
             @Override
             public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
               if (session.isOpened()) {

                 // make request to the /me API
                 Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                   // callback after Graph API response with user object
                   @Override
                   public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                     if (user != null) {
                         System.out.println(user.getName());
                         System.out.println(user.getBirthday());
                         System.out.println(user.getFirstName());
                         System.out.println(user.getLastName());
                         System.out.println(user.getLink());
                         System.out.println(user.getUsername());
                         System.out.println(user.getLocation());
                         System.out.println("facebook user id" + user.getId());
                        System.out.println(user.asMap().get("email").toString());
                        // Session.OpenRequest open = new Session.OpenRequest(Login)
                     }
                   }
                 });
               }
             }
           });
    }
    /**
     * Function to login into facebook
     * */
    public void loginToFacebook() {

        mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
        long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

        if (access_token != null) {
            facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);

            btnFbLogin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            // Making get profile button visible
        //  btnFbGetProfile.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // Making post to wall visible
            //btnPostToWall.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // Making show access tokens button visible
            //btnShowAccessTokens.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            Log.d("FB Sessions", "" + facebook.isSessionValid());
        }

        if (expires != 0) {
            facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
        }

        if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
            facebook.authorize(this,
                    new String[] { "email", "publish_actions" },
                    new DialogListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCancel() {
                            // Function to handle cancel event
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                            // Function to handle complete event
                            // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                            editor.putString("access_token",
                                    facebook.getAccessToken());
                            editor.putLong("access_expires",
                                    facebook.getAccessExpires());
                            editor.commit();

                            // Making Login button invisible
                            btnFbLogin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                            // Making logout Button visible
                        //  btnFbGetProfile.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            // Making post to wall visible
                            //btnPostToWall.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            // Making show access tokens button visible
                            //btnShowAccessTokens.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(DialogError error) {
                            // Function to handle error

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                            // Function to handle Facebook errors

                        }

                    });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


    /**
     * Get Profile information by making request to Facebook Graph API
     * */
    public void getProfileInformation() {
        mAsyncRunner.request("me", new RequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                Log.d("Profile", response);
                String json = response;
                try {
                    // Facebook Profile JSON data
                    JSONObject profile = new JSONObject(json);

                    // getting name of the user
                    final String name = profile.getString("name");

                    // getting email of the user
                    final String email = profile.getString("email");

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name: " + name + "\nEmail: " + email, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    });


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                    Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                    Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Function to post to facebook wall
     * */
    public void postToWall() {
        // post on user's wall.
        facebook.dialog(this, "feed", new DialogListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Function to show Access Tokens
     * */
    public void showAccessTokens() {
        String access_token = facebook.getAccessToken();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Access Token: " + access_token, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    /**
     * Function to Logout user from Facebook
     * */
    public void logoutFromFacebook() {
        mAsyncRunner.logout(this, new RequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                Log.d("Logout from Facebook", response);
                if (Boolean.parseBoolean(response) == true) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // make Login button visible
                            btnFbLogin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            // making all remaining buttons invisible
                            /*btnFbGetProfile.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            btnPostToWall.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            btnShowAccessTokens.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);*/
                        }

                    });

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                    Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                    Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
            }
        });
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this link of your answer & let me know if you find any problem in fb integration.

[Unable to get emailId after login through fb in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34070772/unable-to-get-emailid-after-login-through-fb-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

use this code.

LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback() {

```
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult result) {
            new GraphRequest();
            // SocialSdkPrefrences.getInstance().setAccessToken(result.getAccessToken().getToken());
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(result.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                    FacebookGraphUser fbGraphUser = (FacebookGraphUser) JsonUtil.toModel(response.getRawResponse(), FacebookGraphUser.class);
                    if (fbGraphUser != null) {
                        String image_url = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + fbGraphUser.getId() + "/picture?type=large";

  //                      UniversalImageLoaderUtil.loadImageWithDefaultImage(image_url, (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.user_image), null, R.drawable.place_holder_album);
                        User user=new User(fbGraphUser.getEmail(),image_url,profile.getName(),Long.parseLong(fbGraphUser.getId()));
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        Log.d("social", gson.toJson(user));
                        if (fbGraphUser.getEmail() != null) {
                            if (Util.isValidEmail(fbGraphUser.getEmail())) {
                                new SocialLogInAsyncTask(LoginActivity.this, user).execute();
                            } else {
                                Toast.showShortToast(LoginActivity.this, "You have not valid email,cant login");
                            }
                        } else {
                            Toast.showShortToast(LoginActivity.this, "You have not email,cant login");
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.showErrorToast(LoginActivity.this, R.string.error_signup);
                    }
                }
            });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender,birthday,picture.width(300)");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d("tag", "cancel facebook login");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.d("tag", "error in login" + error.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

call this in your main Activity or the activity that is using FaceBookSignIn method

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(MainActivity.this);
```

add this method in your activity

```
public void FaceBookSignIn() {
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    loginType = Constants.loginTypeFaceBook;

    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.this, Arrays.asList("email", "user_photos", "public_profile"));
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            DisplaySnackBar.display(getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Success", true);

            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject jsonObject, GraphResponse graphResponse) {

                    try {
                            String email = jsonObject.getString(Constants.FacebookEmail),
                            String name = jsonObject.getString(Constants.FacebookName),
                            String firstName = jsonObject.getString(Constants.FacebookFirstName),
                            String lastName = jsonObject.getString(Constants.FacebookLastName),
                            String id = jsonObject.getString(Constants.FacebookID);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,first_name,last_name,birthday,email");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            DisplaySnackBar.display(getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Sign In Cancel", true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            DisplaySnackBar.display(getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Error", true);
        }
    });

}
```

Don't forget to add this dependency in your gradle build file

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.5.0'
```

Comment: Hello friend, i am using this code but its occured so many errors .could you send the full code?

Comment: Hello Zubair,I am using eclipse and used facebook sdk 3.22.0 version.and i am not getting the emailid .Could i run your code?Could you share a full code.

Comment: I think you should move to android studio because it is easy to to integrate things in android studio and i have coded it in android studio, i will update my answer and it is working in android studio

Comment: Hi Zubair,One of my colleague using this code in android studio, but its not working.Here is the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34070772/unable-to-get-emailid-after-login-through-fb-in-android

Comment: have he tried my code because i have used it and its working for me